# Change bibliography format in a revtex4-1

Tags: bibliographies, positioning, revtex

I'm writing a Lab report for one of my assestments, using `revtex4-1` document class. This class, in particular, displays the bibliography at the bottom and breaks columns with a line crossing them.

I need my bibliography be shown within columns, and not breaking them. Is a particular requirement of my teacher (not kidding). I tried to move on to a new document class (`article`), but this bring more troubles because it has a different abstract enviroment.

Could someone tell me how can I change the bibliography, or create a new one from scratch?

```
\documentclass[reprint,
showpacs,preprintnumbers,showkeys,
amsmath,amssymb,
aps,
pra,
letterpaper,twoside]{revtex4-1}
\includepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
Science

\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}
\bibliography{/home/juan/Escritorio/Jabref/prct2mod.bib}
\end{document}
```

This is the way my document class shows the bibliography:

[image]

**I need to be shown like this:**

[image]

Comment: Could you please add also your `prct2mod.bib` or, at least, some bib items of it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware this is an old post, but here is the code I added to the preamble to solve this problem: `\def\bibsection{\section*{\refname}}`